# Value Error while dividing two columns of a dataframe. (.all() and .any() are also not working)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the dataframe info:

```
new_final.info() 

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 12 entries, 1 to 13
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
 0   DorW             12 non-null     object
 1   date             12 non-null     object
 2   source           12 non-null     object
 3   AU               12 non-null     int32 
 4   impressions      12 non-null     int32 
 5   clicks           12 non-null     int32 
 6   pdp              12 non-null     int32 
 7   CABN             12 non-null     int32 
 8   order_completed  12 non-null     int32 
dtypes: int32(6), object(3)
memory usage: 672.0+ bytes
```

I want a new column which is the division of pdp/impression, I have tried all these methods but still get these errors how do I fix it?

```
new_final['impression_to_pdp'] = (new_final['pdp']/new_final['impressions']) 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

new_final['impression_to_pdp'] = (new_final['pdp']/new_final['impressions']).any() 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

new_final['impression_to_pdp'] = (new_final['pdp']/new_final['impressions']).all() 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

DataFrame
[image: Data]

Comment: This is quite interesting. I would have thought int32 / int32 would be ok. Is there a way for us to see the underlying data in the dataframe please?

Comment: Did you look at the data itself?

Comment: I have added the data, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are normal integers contained in lists, it should work in this way

```
new_final['impression_to_pdp'] = new_final['pdp']/new_final['impressions']
```

but, if they are numpy arrays then you must do like

```
import numpy as np
new_final['impression_to_pdp'] = np.divide(new_final['pdp'].values, new_final['impressions'].values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure trial and error, did you try without the brackets?:

```
new_final['impression_to_pdp'] = new_final['pdp']/new_final['impressions']
```

Comment: No, brackets are not reason.

Comment: yes I tried without brackets, I am getting the same error.